# Prolog Find N prime numbers

Tags: prolog, primes

I have a problem with the recursive function of Prolog. I believe I am not implementing it right and need help.

I need to generate the first N prime numbers and return it in a list. Generating the prime number is not an issue, but rather, generating it in a list is the issue I have.

This is the part of the relevant code:

```
genList(_, 0, _).
genList(X, N, PrimeList, PrimeList):-
    N > 0,
    isprime(X),
    X1 is X +1,
    N1 is N -1,
    genList(X1,N1,[X|PrimeList], [X|PrimeList]),!.
genList(X, N, PrimeList, PrimeList):-
    N>0,
    \+isprime(X),
    X1 is X + 1,
    genList(X1,N,PrimeList, PrimeList).
```

This is what I type into the Prolog interpreter:

```
genList(1,N, [],L).
```

For the 1st line, how do I make the base case such that when `N=0`, I stop recursing? Is this correct?

As for the next 2 clauses, I am having difficulty in thinking in terms of logic programming. I definitely feel that this is not logic programming style.

I want to say that when `isPrime(X)` fails, we continue to the next number without saving anything, but when `isPrime(X)` is true, then we recurse and continue to the next number, saving `X`.

How do I do that in Prolog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't need 4 arguments to your main predicate if you only want two. Here you want the list of the first primes up to `N`. So an argument for `N` and an argument for the list should be enough:

```
primeList(N, L) :-
    % eventually in the body a call to a worker predicate with more arguments
```

Now here, your logic is explained in those terms:

```
primeList(N, [N|L]) :-
    % If we're not at the base case yet
    N > 0,
    % If N is a prime
    isPrime(N),
    NewN is N - 1,
    % Let's recurse and unifie N as the head of our result list in the head
    % of the predicate
    primeList(NewN, L).

primeList(N, L) :-
    % Same as above but no further unification in the head this time.
    N > 0,
    % Because N isn't a prime
    \+ isPrime(N),
    NewN is N - 1,
    primeList(NewN, L).
```

To that you'd have to add the base case

```
primeList(0, []).
```

You could rewrite that with cuts as follows:

```
primeList(0, []) :- !.
primeList(N, [N|L]) :-
    isPrime(N),
    !,
    NewN is N - 1,
    primeList(NewN, L).
primeList(N, L) :-
    NewN is N - 1,
    primeList(NewN, L).
```

Comment: Hey Mog!

Sincerely appreciate your comments in the code. It helped me clear up alot of doubts I had while trying to solve this.

A question about the CUT though. in the code that employs the cut, in the 2nd clause

'code'isPrime(N),
!,
NewN is N-1,'code'
when you reach !, is it correct to say it will stop the recursion in that predicate, and move on to the next one (where you dont test if N is prime)?

Thanks.

Comment: Nah, cut just means that choice points will be removed. Search for choice points and cut and you should find good ressources :)

Comment: @ali with the new question asked about this answer I realized I didn't even answer your first question properly. Anyway, hope you successfully adapted it to your problem!

Comment: Haha its cool, yeap I edited it to answer the question. Thanks loads!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you meant to write:

```
genList(N, L) :- genList(2, N, L, []).

genList(X, N, L, Z):-  % L-Z is the result: primes list of length N
    N > 0 ->
      ( isprime(X) -> L=[X|T], N1 is N-1 ; L=T, N1 is N ),
      X1 is X + 1,
      genList(X1,N1,T,Z)
    ;
      L = Z.
```

The *if-then-else* construct embodies the cuts. And you're right, it's essentially a *functional* programming style.

---

We can introduce a little twist to it, disallowing requests for 0 primes (there's no point to it anyway), so that we also get back the last generated prime:

```
genList(1, [2], 2) :- !.
genList(N, [2|L], PN) :- N>1, L=[3|_], N2 is N-2, gen_list(N2, L, [PN]).

gen_list(N, L, Z) :- L=[P|_], X is P+2, gen_list(X, N, L, Z).

gen_list(X, N, L, Z) :-  % get N more odd primes into L's tail
    N > 0 ->
      ( isprime(X) -> L=[_|T], T=[X|_], N1 is N-1 ; L=T, N1 is N ),
      X1 is X + 2,
      gen_list(X1,N1,T,Z)
    ;
      L = Z.           % primes list's last node
```

Run it:

```
?- genList(8,L,P).

L = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
P = 19
```

This also enables us to stop and continue the primes generation from the point where we stopped, instead of starting over from the beginning:

```
?- L = [3|_], gen_list(8, L, Z),    Z=[P10|_],  writeln([2|L]), 
              gen_list(10, Z, Z2),  Z2=[P20],  writeln(Z).

[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29|_G1037]
[29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71]

P10 = 29
P20 = 71
```