# List of Nth prime numbers Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm trying to learn prolog and now I'm trying to print a list of the Nth primenumber:

```
primes(N, N).
primes(N, F):-
    prime(F),
    write(F), nl,
    NewF is F + 1,
    primes(N, NewF).

primes(N):-
    primes(N, 2).
```

Prime/1 checks wheter the given number is a prime.

The output for primes(10) will be 2, 3 where it should be 2, 3, 5, 7, because when the NewF after 3 (which will be 4) is not a prime. So it will also not execute the write(F) nor the recursive call. I wondered how I could fix this, so it will not write F when it's not a prime but still execute the part after that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prolog Find N prime numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446407/prolog-find-n-prime-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add the clause:

```
primes(N, F):-
    \+prime(F), nl,
    NewF is F + 1,
    primes(N, NewF).
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this answer doesn't exactly respond to the OP question (my `getPrimeList(N, L)` create a list `L` with all prime number from zero to `N`; the OP ask for first `N` prime numbers) but... just for fun... I've tried to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
getListDisp(Top, Val, []) :-
  Val > Top.

getListDisp(Top, V0, [V0 | Tail]) :-
  V0 =< Top,
  V1 is V0+2,
  getListDisp(Top, V1, Tail).

reduceList(_, _, [], []).

reduceList(Step, Exclude, [Exclude | Ti], Lo) :-
  NextE is Exclude+Step,
  reduceList(Step, NextE, Ti, Lo).

reduceList(Step, Exclude, [H | Ti], [H | To]) :-
  Exclude > H,
  reduceList(Step, Exclude, Ti, To).

reduceList(Step, Exclude, [H | Ti], [H | To]) :-
  Exclude < H,
  NextE is Exclude+Step,
  reduceList(Step, NextE, Ti, To).

eratSieve([], []).

eratSieve([Prime | Ti], [Prime | To]) :-
  Step is 2*Prime,
  Exclude is Prime+Step,
  reduceList(Step, Exclude, Ti, Lo),
  eratSieve(Lo, To).

getPrimeList(Top, []) :-
  Top < 2.

getPrimeList(Top, [2 | L]) :-
  Top >= 2,
  getListDisp(Top, 3, Ld),
  eratSieve(Ld, L).
```

I repeat: not really an answer; just for fun (as the OP, I'm trying to learn Prolog).